# Spark -Shell error in command prompt

Tags: apache-spark, windows-7, environment-variables

[image: Error]

I am trying to Install Spark in Windows 7 but when running the spark-shell command in cmd it is throwing error. One problem is that the 'Path' variable is in System Variables and not in User variable under the Environment Variables. Tried creating PATH under the User variable also but the error remains. Please help.

Thank you

Comment: Issue resolved. The problem was with the jdk installation path.

Answer (score 0):

The Spark's bin folder is not in your `PATH` environment variable. Try `bin/spark-shell`.